# Is there a way to know how many times a process has received a particular signal

Tags: linux

I have a process which receives a specific real time signal periodically . Is there a way to know how many times the signal has been received ( or caught) outside the code. Any commands or /proc files .

Comment: The code which is handling signal (executable file of process) should have some increment counter.

Comment: Whether it **should** or not, the code which is handling signal (executable file of process) **must** have some increment counter in order for you to get the information your want.